# Multiple directives [placeholder, quickDatepicker] asking for new/isolated scope on

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created an application with angularjs with **[ngQuickDate](https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngQuickDate)**, the application is working fine, but the problem is i cannot change the placeholder , when i use

```
<quick-datepicker ng-model='myDate' date-format='EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy' placeholder='Pick a Date' disable-timepicker='true'></quick-datepicker>
```

I am getting

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [placeholder, quickDatepicker] asking for new/isolated scope on: <quick-datepicker ng-model='myDate' date-format='EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy' placeholder='Pick a Date' disable-timepicker='true'></quick-datepicker>
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: is there a directive named placeholder that you are using.. if yes, can you please share the code of that directive.

Comment: i don't know, whether there is any directive like that since we are using many plugins....if that is the case what will i do

Comment: just grep the files and check if you have any directive like that...